# Problem When Creating Scratch Org

Tags: salesforcedx, error, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

I'm trying to create a Scratch ORG, but everytime I get the same error:

`Failed to deploy settings to scratch org.`

When I run Terminal, I got the following message:

`shape/settings/Bot.settings        Bot        Not available for deploy for this organization`.

I checked the repo of the project, and this path doesn't exists.
The Devhub is configured properly, and I think I'm executing the command in the right path.

Anyone can help me solving this?

**Other Infos**

**Order I executed the commands**:

sfdx force:auth:web:login -a MyDevHub -r https://login.salesforce.com;

sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json -v MyDevHub -a ScratchXXX - I got the error Here;

**My Path**:
C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\project\rootFolder>

**Scratch Org Definition File**:

```
{"orgName": "MyProject",

  "edition": "Enterprise",

  "features": [

    "PersonAccounts",
    "ServiceCloud",
    "Entitlements",
    "Communities",
    "PartnerCommunity",
    "MarketingUser"
  ],
  "settings": {

    "communitiesSettings": {
      "enableNetworksEnabled": true
      },
    "chatterSettings": {
      "enableChatter": true
    }
  }
}
```

```
sfdx force:config:list
=== Config
Name                   Value                   Location
─────────────────────  ──────────────────────  ────────
defaultdevhubusername  SomeOtherOrg            Global
defaultusername        MyDevHub                 Local
```

Comment: Could you [edit] to share your scratch org definition file?

Comment: Edited it @DavidReed, thanks for the help!

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a configuration set to pin your Salesforce API version in SFDX, perhaps? `sfdx force:config:list`.

Comment: I don't understood well your question.

I executed the line of code you sent me:


`defaultdevhubusername  SomeOtherOrg       Global
defaultusername              MyDevHub             Local`

It didn't returned the APi version of any of the orgs.

The error could be related to the fact that :"defaultdevhubusername " is not assigned to the org that I'm currently working with?

Comment: Added to the OP for better understanding! Thanks again! @DavidReed

Comment: Maybe try adding `shape/settings/Bot.settings` to the [`.forceignore`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm) file? The bot thingy could be related to some dependent feature not available for your scratch org configuration.

Comment: I'll try This @Raul